# Installing wifi using rtlwifi_new fails

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

Trying to install [rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/blob/master/README.md) using ~~:~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install 
I see these errors:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/build M=/home/rahul/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]:Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
./scripts/gcc-version.sh:line 26:gcc:command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh:line 27:gcc:command not found
make[1]:gcc:Command not found
make[1]:gcc:Command not found
make[1]:gcc:Command not found
make[1]:gcc:Command not found
 CC[M] /home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/btcoexists/halbtc8192e2ant.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target 'home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/btcoexists/halbtc8192e2ant.o' failed
make[3]: ***[/home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/btcoexists/halbtc8192e2ant.o] Error 127
scripts/Makefile.build:515:recipe for target 'home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/btcoexists/' failed
make[2]: ***[/home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/btcoexists/] Error 2
Makefile:1614:recipe for target '_module_/home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/' failed
make[1]: ***[_module_/home/rahul/rtlwifi_new/] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic'
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'all' failed
make:*** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Install `build-essential` first.

Comment: Editing tips are at http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code - adding a large block of text without making sure it's easy to read turns people off and results in fewer answers.